# swapon: /dev/sdb1: swapon failed: Invalid argument

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap

I am unable to mount a swap partition

Terminal code:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     7831551     3914752   82  Linux swap / Solaris
root@chrubuntu:/home/user# swapon -v /dev/sdb1
swapon on /dev/sdb1
swapon: /dev/sdb1: found swap signature: version 1, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /dev/sdb1: pagesize=4096, swapsize=4008706048, devsize=4008706048
swapon: /dev/sdb1: swapon failed: Invalid argument
root@chrubuntu:/home/user#
```

Can someone help?

EDIT:

Output of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="63dbf7c2-877c-4a5e-8281-8be811c60056" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="ROOT-A" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="2678643c-7148-427e-99b9-3af143dedcf3" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="38794eb2-bdc4-4f2a-97fd-0100fa5600a0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: LABEL="OEM" UUID="e39a733b-31fd-48df-8645-0e64e14d3f10" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda12: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="7B3E-EAE9" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="a4637af0-b82f-4247-ace4-c1621d2fdb7a" TYPE="swap"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sdb1
```

and then `swapon`.

Comment: Maybe check the partition first, is it really a swap partition?  If it really is then just remake swap as falconer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

On some system, disk based swap is turned off by default. In order to enable, run,

```
sudo sysctl vm.disk_based_swap=1
```

Now `sudo swapon <SWAPFILE_PATH>` should work as expected.

Ref.: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kubernetes-users/uhl5R24EOlY/o2kQSz2fBwAJ